# widget's leaveEvent() is missed when scrolling through the encapsulating QScrollArea()

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I have a grid of `QWidget()`s in a `QScrollArea()`. I override their `leaveEvent()` for a particular reason (more on that later). When moving around with the mouse pointer, the `leaveEvent()` is triggered just fine. But when I keep the mouse pointer still and scroll through the `QScrollArea()` with my scrollwheel, the mouse pointer effectively leaves the widget without triggering a `leaveEvent()`.

### 1. Some context

I'm working on an application to browse through Arduino libraries:

[image]

What you see in the screenshot is a `QScrollArea()` in the middle with a scrollbar on the right and one at the bottom. This `QScrollArea()` contains a large `QFrame()` that holds all the widgets in its `QGridLayout()`. Each widget - usually a `QLabel()` or `QPushButton()` - has a lightgrey border. This way, I visualize the grid they're in.

### 2. Lighting up a whole row

When clicking on a widget, I want the whole row to light up. To achieve this, I override the `mousePressEvent()` for each of them:
<sub>Note: In practice, I just make each widget a subclasses from a custom class

`CellWidget()`, such that I need this method-override only once.</sub>

```py
def mousePressEvent(self, e:QMouseEvent) -> None:
    '''
    Set 'blue' property True for all neighbors.
    '''
    for w in self.__neighbors:
        w.setProperty("blue", True)
        w.style().unpolish(w)
        w.style().polish(w)
        w.update()
    super().mousePressEvent(e)
    return
```

The variable `self.__neighbors` is a reference each widget keeps to all its neighboring widgets at the left and right side. This way, each widget has access to all widgets from its own row.

As you can see, I set the property `"blue"` from each widget. This has an effect in the StyleSheet. For example, this is the stylesheet I give to the `QLabel()` widgets:

```py
# Note: 'self' is the QLabel() widget.
self.setStyleSheet(f"""
    QLabel {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #2e3436;
        border-left:   1px solid #eeeeec;
        border-top:    1px solid #eeeeec;
        border-right:  1px solid #d3d7cf;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d7cf;
    }
    QLabel[blue = true] {
        background-color: #d5e1f0;
    }
""")
```

The `unpolish()` and `polish()` methods ensure that the stylesheet gets reloaded (I think?) and the `update()` method invokes a repaint. The procedure works nice. I click on any given widget, and the whole row lights up blue!

### 3. Turn off the (blue) light

To turn it off, I override the `leaveEvent()` method:

```py
def leaveEvent(self, e:QEvent) -> None:
    '''
    Clear 'blue' property for all neighbors.
    '''
    for w in self.__neighbors:
        w.setProperty("blue", False)
        w.style().unpolish(w)
        w.style().polish(w)
        w.update()
    super().leaveEvent(e)
    return
```

So the whole row remains lighted up until you leave the widget with your mouse pointer. The `leaveEvent()` clears the `'blue'` property for all neighbors and forces a repaint on them.

### 4. The problem

But there is a weakness. When I keep my mouse at the same position and I scroll the mousewheel down, the mouse pointer effectively leaves the widget without triggering a `leaveEvent()`. The absence of such `leaveEvent()` breaks my solution. While keeping the mouse still and scrolling down, you can click several rows and they all remain blue.

### 5. System info

I'm working on an application for both Windows and Linux. The application is written in `Python 3.8` and uses `PyQt5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `enterEvent` and `leaveEvent` obviously depend on mouse movements, and since the scrolling does not involve any movement your approach won't work until the user slightly moves the mouse.

I can think about two possible workarounds, but both of them are a bit *hacky* and not very elegant. In both cases, I'm subclassing the scroll area and override the [`viewportEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewportEvent)

### Slightly move the mouse

Since those events require a mouse movement, let's move the mouse (and then move it back):

```
class ScrollArea(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def fakeMouseMove(self):
        pos = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
        # slightly move the mouse
        QtGui.QCursor.setPos(pos + QtCore.QPoint(1, 1))
        # ensure that the application correctly processes the mouse movement
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        # restore the previous position
        QtGui.QCursor.setPos(pos)

    def viewportEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == event.Wheel:
            # let the viewport handle the event correctly, *then* move the mouse
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.fakeMouseMove)
        return super().viewportEvent(event)
```

### Emulate the enter and leave events

This uses [`widgetAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#widgetAt) and creates fake enter and leave events sent to the relative widgets, which is not very good for performance: `widgetAt` might be slow, and repolishing the widgets also takes some time.

```
class ScrollArea(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def viewportEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == event.Wheel:
            old = QtWidgets.QApplication.widgetAt(event.globalPos())
            res = super().viewportEvent(event)
            new = QtWidgets.QApplication.widgetAt(event.globalPos())
            if new != old:
                QtWidgets.QApplication.postEvent(old, 
                    QtCore.QEvent(QtCore.QEvent.Leave))
                QtWidgets.QApplication.postEvent(new, 
                    QtCore.QEvent(QtCore.QEvent.Enter))
            return res
        return super().viewportEvent(event)
```

Comment: The same issue will occur when scrolling with the arrow keys, so checking wheel events is not sufficient. Some performance improvements could be made by ignoring horizontal scrolling events and checking whether the mouse is over the relevant area of the viewport.

Comment: @ekhumoro right, I didn't think about arrow keys. About horizontal scrolling, considering that some mice allow that (and, at least on Linux, alt-scroll results in horizontal scrolling), I thought I could leave that, even if the OP seems to be only interested in highlighting the whole row. About the last note, maybe it's enough to ensure that the mouse is on the viewport?

Comment: To track both wheel and arrow key scrolling I was thinking you could just connect to the `valueChanged` signal of the vertical-scrollbar. There's no need to track the other scrollbar, because the current row never changes during horizontal scrolling. As for the other point: on reflection, the performance concerns are probably premature optimisation (since it's hard to know what the qt docs mean by "this function can be slow").

Comment: Hi musicamante, thank you very much for your great reply! Emulating the events seems like the best option to me now. It's a nice solution. Thank you @ekhumoro for the suggestions.